# Is jQuery $.browser Deprecated?

Tags: jquery, browser

Can someone tell me if I am correct in believing that jQuery's $.browser is/has been deprecated?

Will my existing implementations continue to work?  If not, is there an easy to implement alternative.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/ Category: deprecated.

Comment: Why has this been marked down?  It might be a trivial question to some but if I don't know of an alternative it's a valid thing to ask.

Comment: Or just add plugin: https://github.com/gabceb/jquery-browser-plugin

Answer (score 71, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/):

> The $.browser property is deprecated in jQuery 1.3, and its functionality may be moved to a team-supported plugin in a future release of jQuery.

So, yes, it is deprecated, but your existing implementations will continue to work. If the functionality is removed, it will likely be easily accessible using a plugin.

As to whether there is an alternative... The answer is "yes, probably". It is far, far better to do feature detection using [`$.support`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support) rather than browser detection: detect the actual feature you need, not the browser that provides it. Most important features that vary from browser to browser are detected with that.

---

**Update 16 February 2013:** In jQuery 1.9, this feature was removed ([docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/)). It is far better not to use it. If you really, really *must* use its functionality, you can restore it with the [jQuery Migrate](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/) plugin.

Comment: Problem with `$.support` is, how do I detect if I'm using IE 7, and therefore need to add CSS tweaks to fix my page?

Comment: @Rocket [Conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) would be better, surely.

Comment: lonesomeday - Thank you for that additional comment.  We all try to build our knowledge and need help at times.

Comment: lonesomeday - It good to here that my implement tations will continue to work.  I'll read up on $.support.

Comment: and `$.browser` has been removed from `jQuery 1.9`

Comment: There are so many quirks with IE and different IE versions. Yes IE 7 supports animations, but NO I don't want my users to see it! I'ts horrible. So $.browser is just really handy in this case.

Comment: With the JQuery Migrate plugin, the .browser() function still doesn't work. I must be doing something wrong here.

Comment: $.support is also deprecated from v1.9

Answer (score 96):

### Second Question

> Will my existing implementations continue to work? If not, is there an
>   easy to implement alternative.

The answer is **yes**, but not without a little work.

$.browser is an official plugin which was included in older versions of jQuery, so like any plugin you can simple copy it and incorporate it into your project or you can simply add it to the end of any jQuery release.

I have extracted the code for you incase you wish to use it.

---

```
// Limit scope pollution from any deprecated API
(function() {

    var matched, browser;

// Use of jQuery.browser is frowned upon.
// More details: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser
// jQuery.uaMatch maintained for back-compat
    jQuery.uaMatch = function( ua ) {
        ua = ua.toLowerCase();

        var match = /(chrome)[ \/]([\w.]+)/.exec( ua ) ||
            /(webkit)[ \/]([\w.]+)/.exec( ua ) ||
            /(opera)(?:.*version|)[ \/]([\w.]+)/.exec( ua ) ||
            /(msie) ([\w.]+)/.exec( ua ) ||
            ua.indexOf("compatible") < 0 && /(mozilla)(?:.*? rv:([\w.]+)|)/.exec( ua ) ||
            [];

        return {
            browser: match[ 1 ] || "",
            version: match[ 2 ] || "0"
        };
    };

    matched = jQuery.uaMatch( navigator.userAgent );
    browser = {};

    if ( matched.browser ) {
        browser[ matched.browser ] = true;
        browser.version = matched.version;
    }

// Chrome is Webkit, but Webkit is also Safari.
    if ( browser.chrome ) {
        browser.webkit = true;
    } else if ( browser.webkit ) {
        browser.safari = true;
    }

    jQuery.browser = browser;

    jQuery.sub = function() {
        function jQuerySub( selector, context ) {
            return new jQuerySub.fn.init( selector, context );
        }
        jQuery.extend( true, jQuerySub, this );
        jQuerySub.superclass = this;
        jQuerySub.fn = jQuerySub.prototype = this();
        jQuerySub.fn.constructor = jQuerySub;
        jQuerySub.sub = this.sub;
        jQuerySub.fn.init = function init( selector, context ) {
            if ( context && context instanceof jQuery && !(context instanceof jQuerySub) ) {
                context = jQuerySub( context );
            }

            return jQuery.fn.init.call( this, selector, context, rootjQuerySub );
        };
        jQuerySub.fn.init.prototype = jQuerySub.fn;
        var rootjQuerySub = jQuerySub(document);
        return jQuerySub;
    };

})();
```

---

If you're asking why anyone would need a depreciated plugin, I have prepared the following answer.

First and foremost the answer is compatibility. Since jQuery is plugin based, some developers opted to use $.browser and with the latest releases of jQuery which doesn't include $.browser all those plugins where rendered useless.

jQuery did release a [migration plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/), which was created for developers to detect whether their plugin's used any depreciated dependencies such as $.browser.

Although this helped developers patch their plugin's. jQuery dropped $.browser completely so the above fix is probably the only solution until your developers patch or incorporate the above.

**About:** [jQuery.browser](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/)

Comment: This helped me get a 3rd party script that was still using $.browser to work with jQuery 1.9.0. Thanks!

Comment: I found a more official version of this (and other deprecated features) here: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/

Comment: Migrate plugin is a good tool that allows users to see a list of deprecated functions currently if any in there scripts, it does give functionality to deprecated function. Not intended to be a patch.

Comment: Agreed. I since decided to stick with 1.8.3 while I wait for the next gen of the 3rd party script.

Comment: +1, there's bugs in things like the `placeholder` attribute all the way through IE10 that we have to deal with, and require `$.browser` for it...

Comment: Worked for me too :) . I had some old Autocomplete plugin after adding to my mobile website was throwing same error started working fine with your script

Answer (score 6):

Here I present an alternative way to detect a browser, based on feature availability.

To detect only IE, you can use this:

```
if(/*@cc_on!@*/false || typeof ScriptEngineMajorVersion === "function")
{
    //You are using IE>=4 (unreliable for IE11)
}
else
{
    //You are using other browser
}
```

To detect the most popular browsers:

```
if(/*@cc_on!@*/false || typeof ScriptEngineMajorVersion === "function")
{
    //You are using IE >= 4 (unreliable for IE11!!!)
}
else if(window.chrome)
{
    //You are using Chrome or Chromium
}
else if(window.opera)
{
    //You are using Opera >= 9.2
}
else if('MozBoxSizing' in document.body.style)
{
    //You are using Firefox or Firefox based >= 3.2
}
else if({}.toString.call(window.HTMLElement).indexOf('Constructor')+1)
{
    //You are using Safari >= 3.1
}
else
{
    //Unknown
}
```

This answer was updated because IE11 no longer supports conditional compilation (the `/*@cc_on!@*/false` trick).
You can check [Did IE11 remove javascript conditional compilation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20392163/did-ie11-remove-javascript-conditional-compilation) for more informations regarding this topic.
I've used the suggestion they presented there.
Alternatively, you can use `typeof document.body.style.msTransform == "string"` or `document.body.style.msTransform !== window.undefined` or even `'msTransform' in document.body.style`.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this. my date picker was not working after upgrading to VS2013 and dowloading Jquery and Juice from the Nuget Package manager. Pasted the code and everything worked again.

Comment: You are welcome. I use this code to handle all browsers in edge-cases on some of my javascript codes. If ANY of this stops working, and if you detect it, please, tell me as soon as possible.

Comment: /*@cc_on!@*/false returns false for IE edge

Comment: @alex What exact version and build are you using and in which OS? If you are using on a virtual machine, please, can you specify the software and the version?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel - Tested via F12 dev tools, Document Mode = Edge(Default), i type: /*@cc_on!@*/false == true    in the console and it returns false. The full version/build of my IE is: 11.0.9600.17207. OS = Windows 7. Testing in IE on physical machine, not virtual

Comment: @alex I will update this code later. IE11 no longer supports conditional compilation.

Comment: @alex Sorry the delay. I've fixed the answer now. IE really screwed up. But I've managed it. Tell me what you think, please.

Answer (score 4):

> Updated! 3/24/2015 (scroll below hr)

[lonesomeday](https://stackoverflow.com/users/417562/lonesomeday)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9638247/is-jquery-browser-deprecated#answer-9638284) is absolutely correct, I just thought I would add this tidbit. I had made a method a while back for getting browser in Vanilla JS and eventually curved it to replace `jQuery.browser` in later versions of jQuery. It does not interfere with any part of the new jQuery lib, but provides the same functionality of the traditional `jQuery.browser` object, as well as some other little features.

---

New Extended Version!

Is much more thorough for newer browser. Also, 90+% accuracy on mobile testing! I won't say 100%, as I haven't tested on every mobile browser, but new feature adds `$.browser.mobile` boolean/string. It's false if not mobile, else it will be a String name for the mobile device or browser (Best Guesss like: Android, RIM Tablet, iPod, etc...).

One possible caveat, may not work with some older (unsupported) browsers as it is completely reliant on `userAgent` string.

### JS Minified

```
/* quick & easy cut & paste */
;;(function($){if(!$.browser&&1.9<=parseFloat($.fn.jquery)){var a={browser:void 0,version:void 0,mobile:!1};navigator&&navigator.userAgent&&(a.ua=navigator.userAgent,a.webkit=/WebKit/i.test(a.ua),a.browserArray="MSIE Chrome Opera Kindle Silk BlackBerry PlayBook Android Safari Mozilla Nokia".split(" "),/Sony[^ ]*/i.test(a.ua)?a.mobile="Sony":/RIM Tablet/i.test(a.ua)?a.mobile="RIM Tablet":/BlackBerry/i.test(a.ua)?a.mobile="BlackBerry":/iPhone/i.test(a.ua)?a.mobile="iPhone":/iPad/i.test(a.ua)?a.mobile="iPad":/iPod/i.test(a.ua)?a.mobile="iPod":/Opera Mini/i.test(a.ua)?a.mobile="Opera Mini":/IEMobile/i.test(a.ua)?a.mobile="IEMobile":/BB[0-9]{1,}; Touch/i.test(a.ua)?a.mobile="BlackBerry":/Nokia/i.test(a.ua)?a.mobile="Nokia":/Android/i.test(a.ua)&&(a.mobile="Android"),/MSIE|Trident/i.test(a.ua)?(a.browser="MSIE",a.version=/MSIE/i.test(navigator.userAgent)&&0<parseFloat(a.ua.split("MSIE")[1].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,""))?parseFloat(a.ua.split("MSIE")[1].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,"")):"Edge",/Trident/i.test(a.ua)&&/rv:([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})/.test(a.ua)&&(a.version=parseFloat(a.ua.match(/rv:([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})/)[1].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,"")))):/Chrome/.test(a.ua)?(a.browser="Chrome",a.version=parseFloat(a.ua.split("Chrome/")[1].split("Safari")[0].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,""))):/Opera/.test(a.ua)?(a.browser="Opera",a.version=parseFloat(a.ua.split("Version/")[1].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,""))):/Kindle|Silk|KFTT|KFOT|KFJWA|KFJWI|KFSOWI|KFTHWA|KFTHWI|KFAPWA|KFAPWI/i.test(a.ua)?(a.mobile="Kindle",/Silk/i.test(a.ua)?(a.browser="Silk",a.version=parseFloat(a.ua.split("Silk/")[1].split("Safari")[0].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,""))):/Kindle/i.test(a.ua)&&/Version/i.test(a.ua)&&(a.browser="Kindle",a.version=parseFloat(a.ua.split("Version/")[1].split("Safari")[0].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,"")))):/BlackBerry/.test(a.ua)?(a.browser="BlackBerry",a.version=parseFloat(a.ua.split("/")[1].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,""))):/PlayBook/.test(a.ua)?(a.browser="PlayBook",a.version=parseFloat(a.ua.split("Version/")[1].split("Safari")[0].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,""))):/BB[0-9]{1,}; Touch/.test(a.ua)?(a.browser="Blackberry",a.version=parseFloat(a.ua.split("Version/")[1].split("Safari")[0].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,""))):/Android/.test(a.ua)?(a.browser="Android",a.version=parseFloat(a.ua.split("Version/")[1].split("Safari")[0].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,""))):/Safari/.test(a.ua)?(a.browser="Safari",a.version=parseFloat(a.ua.split("Version/")[1].split("Safari")[0].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,""))):/Firefox/.test(a.ua)?(a.browser="Mozilla",a.version=parseFloat(a.ua.split("Firefox/")[1].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,""))):/Nokia/.test(a.ua)&&(a.browser="Nokia",a.version=parseFloat(a.ua.split("Browser")[1].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,""))));if(a.browser)for(var b in a.browserArray)a[a.browserArray[b].toLowerCase()]=a.browser==a.browserArray[b];$.extend(!0,$.browser={},a)}})(jQuery);
/* quick & easy cut & paste */
```

## jsFiddle "jQuery Plugin: Get Browser (Extended Alt Edition)"

```js
/** jQuery.browser
 * @author J.D. McKinstry (2014)
 * @description Made to replicate older jQuery.browser command in jQuery versions 1.9+
 * @see http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/wsqfbe4s/
 *
 * @extends jQuery
 * @namespace jQuery.browser
 * @example jQuery.browser.browser == 'browserNameInLowerCase'
 * @example jQuery.browser.version
 * @example jQuery.browser.mobile @returns BOOLEAN
 * @example jQuery.browser['browserNameInLowerCase']
 * @example jQuery.browser.chrome @returns BOOLEAN
 * @example jQuery.browser.safari @returns BOOLEAN
 * @example jQuery.browser.opera @returns BOOLEAN
 * @example jQuery.browser.msie @returns BOOLEAN
 * @example jQuery.browser.mozilla @returns BOOLEAN
 * @example jQuery.browser.webkit @returns BOOLEAN
 * @example jQuery.browser.ua @returns navigator.userAgent String
 */
;;(function($){if(!$.browser&&1.9<=parseFloat($.fn.jquery)){var a={browser:void 0,version:void 0,mobile:!1};navigator&&navigator.userAgent&&(a.ua=navigator.userAgent,a.webkit=/WebKit/i.test(a.ua),a.browserArray="MSIE Chrome Opera Kindle Silk BlackBerry PlayBook Android Safari Mozilla Nokia".split(" "),/Sony[^ ]*/i.test(a.ua)?a.mobile="Sony":/RIM Tablet/i.test(a.ua)?a.mobile="RIM Tablet":/BlackBerry/i.test(a.ua)?a.mobile="BlackBerry":/iPhone/i.test(a.ua)?a.mobile="iPhone":/iPad/i.test(a.ua)?a.mobile="iPad":/iPod/i.test(a.ua)?a.mobile="iPod":/Opera Mini/i.test(a.ua)?a.mobile="Opera Mini":/IEMobile/i.test(a.ua)?a.mobile="IEMobile":/BB[0-9]{1,}; Touch/i.test(a.ua)?a.mobile="BlackBerry":/Nokia/i.test(a.ua)?a.mobile="Nokia":/Android/i.test(a.ua)&&(a.mobile="Android"),/MSIE|Trident/i.test(a.ua)?(a.browser="MSIE",a.version=/MSIE/i.test(navigator.userAgent)&&0<parseFloat(a.ua.split("MSIE")[1].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,""))?parseFloat(a.ua.split("MSIE")[1].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,"")):"Edge",/Trident/i.test(a.ua)&&/rv:([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})/.test(a.ua)&&(a.version=parseFloat(a.ua.match(/rv:([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})/)[1].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,"")))):/Chrome/.test(a.ua)?(a.browser="Chrome",a.version=parseFloat(a.ua.split("Chrome/")[1].split("Safari")[0].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,""))):/Opera/.test(a.ua)?(a.browser="Opera",a.version=parseFloat(a.ua.split("Version/")[1].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,""))):/Kindle|Silk|KFTT|KFOT|KFJWA|KFJWI|KFSOWI|KFTHWA|KFTHWI|KFAPWA|KFAPWI/i.test(a.ua)?(a.mobile="Kindle",/Silk/i.test(a.ua)?(a.browser="Silk",a.version=parseFloat(a.ua.split("Silk/")[1].split("Safari")[0].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,""))):/Kindle/i.test(a.ua)&&/Version/i.test(a.ua)&&(a.browser="Kindle",a.version=parseFloat(a.ua.split("Version/")[1].split("Safari")[0].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,"")))):/BlackBerry/.test(a.ua)?(a.browser="BlackBerry",a.version=parseFloat(a.ua.split("/")[1].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,""))):/PlayBook/.test(a.ua)?(a.browser="PlayBook",a.version=parseFloat(a.ua.split("Version/")[1].split("Safari")[0].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,""))):/BB[0-9]{1,}; Touch/.test(a.ua)?(a.browser="Blackberry",a.version=parseFloat(a.ua.split("Version/")[1].split("Safari")[0].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,""))):/Android/.test(a.ua)?(a.browser="Android",a.version=parseFloat(a.ua.split("Version/")[1].split("Safari")[0].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,""))):/Safari/.test(a.ua)?(a.browser="Safari",a.version=parseFloat(a.ua.split("Version/")[1].split("Safari")[0].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,""))):/Firefox/.test(a.ua)?(a.browser="Mozilla",a.version=parseFloat(a.ua.split("Firefox/")[1].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,""))):/Nokia/.test(a.ua)&&(a.browser="Nokia",a.version=parseFloat(a.ua.split("Browser")[1].replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,""))));if(a.browser)for(var b in a.browserArray)a[a.browserArray[b].toLowerCase()]=a.browser==a.browserArray[b];$.extend(!0,$.browser={},a)}})(jQuery);
/* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - */

var b = $.browser;
console.log($.browser);    //    see console, working example of jQuery Plugin
console.log($.browser.chrome);

for (var x in b) {
    if (x != 'init')
        $('<tr />').append(
            $('<th />', { text: x }),
            $('<td />', { text: b[x] })
        ).appendTo($('table'));
}
```

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse; }
th, td { border: 1px solid; padding: .25em .5em; vertical-align: top; }
th { text-align: right; }

textarea { height: 500px; width: 100%; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table></table>
```

Answer (score 3):

> "The $.browser property is deprecated in jQuery 1.3, and its functionality may be moved to a team-supported plugin in a future release of jQuery."

From http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/

Comment: `$.browser` is removed in v1.9

Answer (score 0):

From the official documentation at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/:

> This property was removed in jQuery 1.9 and is available only through the jQuery.migrate plugin.

You can use for example `jquery-migrate-1.4.1.js` to keep your existing code or plugins that use $.browser still working while you find a way to totally get rid of $.browser from your code in the future.