# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

This error message is arising from the following code:

```
$.fn.extend({
    chosen: function(options) {
      if ($.browser.msie && ($.browser.version === "6.0" || $.browser.version === "7.0")) {
```

From the file: https://github.com/koenpunt/chosen/edit/master/chosen/chosen.jquery.js

Obviously browser is not defined. Any idea what could be causing this. Same error in Chrome and FF.

Comment: `$.browser` has beeen removed in the latest jQuery. Find solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9638247/is-jquery-browser-deprecated

Comment: Thanks for the link. I have just added it as a jquery plugin. All fixed now.

Answer (score 260, accepted):

`$.browser` was removed from jQuery starting with version 1.9. It is now available [as a plugin](https://github.com/gabceb/jquery-browser-plugin). It's generally recommended to avoid browser detection, which is why it was removed.

Comment: I recommend using the official `jQuery Migrate plugin` as mentioned in the docs http://jquery.com/download/#jquery-migrate-plugin ,