# Jquery Tab did not work well with tinymce?

Tags: jquery, tabs, jquery-tabs

I want to ask about Jquery Tab. I recently use it to some of my web, and it works perfectly. But now I have a web page with tinymce on it, and I don't know why jquery tab didn't work well. It just a bulleted list. I've create an example in

`here`http://jsfiddle.net/weCth/1/

I already call the jquery ui, jquery css.

I hope there are people who have experienced this problem maybe so the tab will works perfectly?

Sorry for my bad English

Comment: Here's an updated fiddle with jQuery, jQueryUI, and TinyMCE included: http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/weCth/3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were getting an error due to a deprecated method: "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"

[**More on that error**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14793331/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-msie-of-undefined)

Try using jQuery 1.8.x: http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/weCth/4/

```
Required code
```

Comment: still not work in my web... I got this error from console log: http://i58.tinypic.com/2089q35.jpg

Comment: Looks like your JS files aren't loading due to some localhost config issue.