# jQuery Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined in drupal

Tags: jquery, drupal

I'm facing following error on my Drupal Website:

```
caught TypeError: Cannot read property 'version' of undefined
jquery.formalize.js?nkmwqx:13 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined
caught TypeError: Cannot read property 'version' of undefined
jquery.formalize.js?nkmwqx:13 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined
jquery.bgiframe.min.js?v=2.1:11 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined
```

Comment: This error is relevant to `jQuery.browser` that has been removed from jq>1.9. Upgrade plugins or downgrade jQuery version. The former, if possible, is of course better. I'd suggest you to test it using jQuery migrate: http://blog.jquery.com/2013/05/08/jquery-migrate-1-2-1-released/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you have the [jQuery update](https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_update) module installed in your Drupal Website.

Try to disable it. Also you can add [jQuery migrate](http://jquery.com/download/).

Answer (score 2):

This issue happens because the "$.browser" property was removed in jQuery 1.9.0. You can fix this problem by adding the code below:

```
<script>
jQuery.browser = {};
(function () {
jQuery.browser.msie = false;
jQuery.browser.version = 0;
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE ([0-9]+)\./)) {
jQuery.browser.msie = true;
jQuery.browser.version = RegExp.$1;
}
})();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is related to jquery version. Please take a look at the below links.

[Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined - jQuery tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14923301/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-msie-of-undefined-jquery-tools)

[Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14793331/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-msie-of-undefined)