# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined - Cloud carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

When implementing cloud carousel, I am getting the following error.

```
Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined
```

The js library of this code is as follows

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// CloudCarousel V1.0.5
// (c) 2011 by R Cecco. <http://www.professorcloud.com>
// MIT License
//
// Reflection code based on plugin by Christophe Beyls <http://www.digitalia.be>
//
// Please retain this copyright header in all versions of the software
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
(function($){function Reflection(img,reflHeight,opacity){var reflection,cntx,imageWidth=img.width,imageHeight=img.width,gradient,parent;parent=$(img.parentNode);this.element=reflection=parent.append("<canvas class='reflection' style='position:absolute'/>").find(':last')[0];if(!reflection.getContext&&$.browser.msie){this.element=reflection=parent.append("<img class='reflection' style='position:absolute'/>").find(':last')[0];reflection.src=img.src;reflection.style.filter="flipv progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity="+(opacity*100)+", style=1, finishOpacity=0, startx=0, starty=0, finishx=0, finishy="+(reflHeight/imageHeight*100)+")"}else{cntx=reflection.getContext("2d");try{$(reflection).attr({width:imageWidth,height:reflHeight});cntx.save();cntx.translate(0,imageHeight-1);cntx.scale(1,-1);cntx.drawImage(img,0,0,imageWidth,imageHeight);cntx.restore();cntx.globalCompositeOperation="destination-out";gradient=cntx.createLinearGradient(0,0,0,reflHeight);gradient.addColorStop(0,"rgba(255, 255, 255, "+(1-opacity)+")");gradient.addColorStop(1,"rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0)");cntx.fillStyle=gradient;cntx.fillRect(0,0,imageWidth,reflHeight)}catch(e){return}}$(reflection).attr({'alt':$(img).attr('alt'),title:$(img).attr('title')})}var Item=function(imgIn,options){this.orgWidth=imgIn.width;this.orgHeight=imgIn.height;this.image=imgIn;this.reflection=null;this.alt=imgIn.alt;this.title=imgIn.title;this.imageOK=false;this.options=options;this.imageOK=true;if(this.options.reflHeight>0){this.reflection=new Reflection(this.image,this.options.reflHeight,this.options.reflOpacity)}$(this.image).css('position','absolute')};var Controller=function(container,images,options){var items=[],funcSin=Math.sin,funcCos=Math.cos,ctx=this;this.controlTimer=0;this.stopped=false;this.container=container;this.xRadius=options.xRadius;this.yRadius=options.yRadius;this.showFrontTextTimer=0;this.autoRotateTimer=0;if(options.xRadius===0){this.xRadius=($(container).width()/2.3)}if(options.yRadius===0){this.yRadius=($(container).height()/6)}this.xCentre=options.xPos;this.yCentre=options.yPos;this.frontIndex=0;this.rotation=this.destRotation=Math.PI/2;this.timeDelay=1000/options.FPS;if(options.altBox!==null){$(options.altBox).css('display','block');$(options.titleBox).css('display','block')}$(container).css({position:'relative',overflow:'hidden'});$(options.buttonLeft).css('display','inline');$(options.buttonRight).css('display','inline');$(options.buttonLeft).bind('mouseup',this,function(event){event.data.rotate(-1);return false});$(options.buttonRight).bind('mouseup',this,function(event){event.data.rotate(1);return false});if(options.mouseWheel){$(container).bind('mousewheel',this,function(event,delta){event.data.rotate(delta);return false})}$(container).bind('mouseover click',this,function(event){clearInterval(event.data.autoRotateTimer);var text=$(event.target).attr('alt');if(text!==undefined&&text!==null){clearTimeout(event.data.showFrontTextTimer);$(options.altBox).html(($(event.target).attr('alt')));$(options.titleBox).html(($(event.target).attr('title')));if(options.bringToFront&&event.type=='click'){var idx=$(event.target).data('itemIndex');var frontIndex=event.data.frontIndex;var diff=(idx-frontIndex)%images.length;if(Math.abs(diff)>images.length/2){diff+=(diff>0?-images.length:images.length)}event.data.rotate(-diff)}}});$(container).bind('mouseout',this,function(event){var context=event.data;clearTimeout(context.showFrontTextTimer);context.showFrontTextTimer=setTimeout(function(){context.showFrontText()},1000);context.autoRotate()});$(container).bind('mousedown',this,function(event){event.data.container.focus();return false});container.onselectstart=function(){return false};this.innerWrapper=$(container).wrapInner('<div style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;"/>').children()[0];this.showFrontText=function(){if(items[this.frontIndex]===undefined){return}$(options.titleBox).html($(items[this.frontIndex].image).attr('title'));$(options.altBox).html($(items[this.frontIndex].image).attr('alt'))};this.go=function(){if(this.controlTimer!==0){return}var context=this;this.controlTimer=setTimeout(function(){context.updateAll()},this.timeDelay)};this.stop=function(){clearTimeout(this.controlTimer);this.controlTimer=0};this.rotate=function(direction){this.frontIndex-=direction;this.frontIndex%=items.length;this.destRotation+=(Math.PI/items.length)*(2*direction);this.showFrontText();this.go()};this.autoRotate=function(){if(options.autoRotate!=='no'){var dir=(options.autoRotate==='right')?1:-1;this.autoRotateTimer=setInterval(function(){ctx.rotate(dir)},options.autoRotateDelay)}};this.updateAll=function(){var minScale=options.minScale;var smallRange=(1-minScale)*0.5;var w,h,x,y,scale,item,sinVal;var change=(this.destRotation-this.rotation);var absChange=Math.abs(change);this.rotation+=change*options.speed;if(absChange<0.001){this.rotation=this.destRotation}var itemsLen=items.length;var spacing=(Math.PI/itemsLen)*2;var radians=this.rotation;var isMSIE=$.browser.msie;this.innerWrapper.style.display='none';var style;var px='px',reflHeight;var context=this;for(var i=0;i<itemsLen;i++){item=items[i];sinVal=funcSin(radians);scale=((sinVal+1)*smallRange)+minScale;x=this.xCentre+(((funcCos(radians)*this.xRadius)-(item.orgWidth*0.5))*scale);y=this.yCentre+(((sinVal*this.yRadius))*scale);if(item.imageOK){var img=item.image;w=img.width=item.orgWidth*scale;h=img.height=item.orgHeight*scale;img.style.left=x+px;img.style.top=y+px;img.style.zIndex=""+(scale*100)>>0;if(item.reflection!==null){reflHeight=options.reflHeight*scale;style=item.reflection.element.style;style.left=x+px;style.top=y+h+options.reflGap*scale+px;style.width=w+px;if(isMSIE){style.filter.finishy=(reflHeight/h*100)}else{style.height=reflHeight+px}}}radians+=spacing}this.innerWrapper.style.display='block';if(absChange>=0.001){this.controlTimer=setTimeout(function(){context.updateAll()},this.timeDelay)}else{this.stop()}};this.checkImagesLoaded=function(){var i;for(i=0;i<images.length;i++){if((images[i].width===undefined)||((images[i].complete!==undefined)&&(!images[i].complete))){return}}for(i=0;i<images.length;i++){items.push(new Item(images[i],options));$(images[i]).data('itemIndex',i)}clearInterval(this.tt);this.showFrontText();this.autoRotate();this.updateAll()};this.tt=setInterval(function(){ctx.checkImagesLoaded()},50)};$.fn.CloudCarousel=function(options){this.each(function(){options=$.extend({},{reflHeight:0,reflOpacity:0.5,reflGap:0,minScale:0.5,xPos:0,yPos:0,xRadius:0,yRadius:0,altBox:null,titleBox:null,FPS:30,autoRotate:'no',autoRotateDelay:1500,speed:0.2,mouseWheel:false,bringToFront:false},options);$(this).data('cloudcarousel',new Controller(this,$('.cloudcarousel',$(this)),options))});return this}})(jQuery);
```

And my code is a simple code like this:

```
<head>
 <title>Cloud Carousel</title>
 <!-- 1. Download and insert the script from Cloud Carousel Website -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javaScript" src="cloud-carousel.1.0.5.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){

        // This initialises carousels on the container elements specified, in this case, carousel1.
        $("#carousel1").CloudCarousel(      
            {           
                // Best is half of the width you set in DIV style of carouselID
                xPos: 285,
                // Determines the central height of the pivot point of the carousel itself.
                yPos: 100,
                buttonLeft: $("#butLeft"),
                buttonRight: $("#butRight"),
                reflHeight: 56,
                reflGap:2,
            }
        );
    });

 </script>
</head>

<body>
 <!-- 2. Declare a div with a given carouselID Name, use style to manage the style and height. You can add background also -->
 <!-- 3. Declare class="cloudcarousel" to all the images sandwitched in between the div tag, these will be the images for the carousel -->
 <div id="carousel1" style="width:570px; height:220px; background:#000;overflow:scroll;">
    <a href="http://www.watchlearnknow.com"><img class="cloudcarousel" soverflow:scroll;rc="images/BlueAppIcon.png" alt="AppIcon1" width="58" height ="58"/></a>
    <a href="http://www.wikipedia.com"><img class="cloudcarousel" src="images/GoldAppIcon.png" alt="AppIcon2" width="58" height ="58"/></a>
    <a href="http://www.wordpress.com"><img class="cloudcarousel" src="images/GreenAppIcon.png" alt="AppIcon3" width="58" height ="58"/></a>
    <a href="http://www.yahoo.com"><img class="cloudcarousel" src="images/OrangeAppIcon.png" alt="AppIcon4" width="58" height ="58"/></a>
    <a href="http://www.apple.com"><img class="cloudcarousel" src="images/RedAppIcon.png" alt="AppIcon5" width="58" height ="58"/></a>
    <a href="http://www.android.com"><img class="cloudcarousel" src="images/PinkAppIcon.png" alt="AppIcon6" width="58" height ="58"/></a>

  <div id="butLeft" style="position:relative;top:20px;left:20px;padding:5px;background:#fff;">&lt;</div>
  <div id="butRight" style="position:relative;top:20px;left:30px;padding:5px;background:#fff;">&gt;</div> 
 </div>
</body>
```

How can I resolve this msie error and more importantly what does it mean?

Comment: jQuery 3.1.1 does not have a `$.browser.msie` flag anymore. You are using a version of jQuery not compatible with your plug-in. The example site for your plugin uses jQuery 1.4.2. The browser sniffing pieces of jQuery were removed in version 1.9.

Comment: you're using an old plugin. find a new one.

Comment: 1.0.5 is the latest plugin that I was able to find! do you know which jquery might be compatible with this @KevinB

Comment: that's unfortunate.

Comment: Perhaps, cloud-carousel hasn't been updated for a while. The last commit of cloud-carousel was 5 years ago (June 2012). Possible alternative - [Flickity](https://flickity.metafizzy.co/)

Comment: Find a new plugin, use the migrate plugin, or use a version of jquery from 6 or so years ago.

Comment: lightSlider is one i've used in the past, maybe give it a try.

Comment: which carousel is the latest that I can use similar to cloud carousel @Flickity-Annjawn

Comment: what do you mean by migrate plugin @KevinB

Comment: I want to create an effect somewhat similar to cloud carousel as in the active should come in front and others should stay in back. Do you know of a way to do that!It would be a great help @KevinB

Comment: @aayushi jquery has a migrate plugin. but no idea if it would actually help you in this case.

Answer (score -1):

Always try to search first, i believe this is a duplicate from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14793331/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-msie-of-undefined):

> $.browser was removed from jQuery starting with version 1.9. It is now
>   available as a [plugin](https://github.com/gabceb/jquery-browser-plugin). It's generally recommended to avoid
>   browser detection, which is why it was removed.

Comment: thanks, but i don't know really know what to do with this link. Can you please elaborate. I am new to jquery . Thanks