# I got an error [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios, vue-component

I am working with vue and here is my code

everything is working fine until I submitting the form. when I submit form and try to update emailForm -> tabs -> en -> data -> name then i got an error.

```
<template>
    <el-form :model="emailForm.tabs" ref="emailForm" class="demo-emailForm" @submit="submitForm('emailForm')">
        <div v-for="(lan, key, index) in emailForm.tabs">
        <el-form-item :label="$t('Template Name')" >
            {{lan.data.name}}
       </el-form-item>
    <el-form>
<template>
<script>
        export default {
            data() {
                return {
                    emailForm: {
                        tabs: {
                            en: {
                                sortHeand: 'en',
                                title: 'English',
                                data: {
                                    name: "ad",
                                    subject: "asda",
                                    html_code: 'asdad',
                                    status: 0
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            methods: {
                submitForm(formName) {
                    this.$refs[formName].validate(valid => {
                        if (valid) {
                            request({
                                url: this.getRoute(),
                                method: "post",
                                data: this[formName].tabs
                            })
                            .then(response => {
                                console.log(response)
                            })
                        }
                    });
                },
            }
        }
</script>
```

Anyone can render this issue ?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you provided correct code? Your `methods` is inside of `data()`

Comment: You definitely missing a `}` https://jsfiddle.net/Jubels/eywraw8t/374456/

Comment: Yes that was my mistake let me edit this..., in my my side it's perfect

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14793331/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-msie-of-undefined)

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to read property `name` from variable/object `data` but `data` is `undefined` so it can't read the property `name` from it.

Comment: No I can see my data when I print {{lan.data}} its working fine but when I print {{lan.data.name}} it gives an error

Comment: Show us what you get in `{{lan.data}}`

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal   { "name": "ad", "subject": "asda", "html_code": "asdad", "status": 0 }

Comment: Keep {{lan.data.name}} in same line where you kept {{lan.data}}

Comment: The same happens to me. I can see the but get error in the console