# TextAreaExpander plugin for jQuery: Error for know the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I using the plugin's programmed in javascript or Query from two years.

Now I opened this my project with my plugin for expander the textarea.

I have this new error on this sentence (analizying with Firebug).
    TypeError: $.browser is undefined

```
var hCheck = !($.browser.msie || $.browser.opera);
```

Why?

Info

```
/**
* TextAreaExpander plugin for jQuery
* v1.0
* Expands or contracts a textarea height depending on the
* quatity of content entered by the user in the box.
*
* By Craig Buckler, Optimalworks.net
*
* As featured on SitePoint.com:
* http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2009/07/29/build-auto-expanding-textarea-1/
*
* Please use as you wish at your own risk.
*/
/**
* Usage:
*
* From JavaScript, use:
* $(<node>).TextAreaExpander(<minHeight>, <maxHeight>);
* where:
* <node> is the DOM node selector, e.g. "textarea"
* <minHeight> is the minimum textarea height in pixels (optional)
* <maxHeight> is the maximum textarea height in pixels (optional)
*
* Alternatively, in you HTML:
* Assign a class of "expand" to any <textarea> tag.
* e.g. <textarea name="textarea1" rows="3" cols="40" class="expand"></textarea>
*
* Or assign a class of "expandMIN-MAX" to set the <textarea> minimum and maximum height.
* e.g. <textarea name="textarea1" rows="3" cols="40" class="expand50-200"></textarea>
* The textarea will use an appropriate height between 50 and 200 pixels.
*/
(function($) {
// jQuery plugin definition
$.fn.TextAreaExpander = function(minHeight=21, maxHeight) {
var hCheck = !($.browser.msie || $.browser.opera);
// resize a textarea
function ResizeTextarea(e) {
// event or initialize element?
e = e.target || e;
// find content length and box width
var vlen = e.value.length, ewidth = e.offsetWidth;
if (vlen != e.valLength || ewidth != e.boxWidth) {
if (hCheck && (vlen < e.valLength || ewidth != e.boxWidth)) e.style.height = "0px";
var h = Math.max(e.expandMin, Math.min(e.scrollHeight, e.expandMax))+2;
e.style.overflow = (e.scrollHeight > h ? "auto" : "hidden");
e.style.height = h + "px";
e.valLength = vlen;
e.boxWidth = ewidth;
}
return true;
};
// initialize
this.each(function() {
// is a textarea?
if (this.nodeName.toLowerCase() != "textarea") return;
// set height restrictions
var p = this.className.match(/expand(\d+)\-*(\d+)*/i);
this.expandMin = minHeight || (p ? parseInt('0'+p[1], 10) : 0);
this.expandMax = maxHeight || (p ? parseInt('0'+p[2], 10) : 99999);
// initial resize
ResizeTextarea(this);
// zero vertical padding and add events
if (!this.Initialized) {
this.Initialized = true;
$(this).css("padding-top", 0).css("padding-bottom", 0);
$(this).bind("keyup", ResizeTextarea).bind("focus", ResizeTextarea);
}
});
return this;
};
})(jQuery);
// initialize all expanding textareas
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery("textarea[class*=expand]").TextAreaExpander();
})
```

Comment: Are you sure `jQuery` is loaded ?

Comment: jQuery's `browser` property is deprecated.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9638247/is-jquery-browser-deprecated

Comment: Which version of jquery are you using ? $.browser has been removed as of 1.9. Check here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/

Comment: <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

Comment: For information with this sentence:
var hCheck = !(jQuery.support.boxModel || (verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("Opera"))!=-1);

I replace and work's equal with old sentence.
Then this is a solution 
var hCheck = !(jQuery.support.boxModel || (verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("Opera"))!=-1);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved my problem, I replaced this code:

```
 (function($) {
    // jQuery plugin definition
    $.fn.TextAreaExpander = function(minHeight, maxHeight) {
      minHeight=21;
    var nAgt=navigator.userAgent;
    var verOffset;
    var hCheck = !(jQuery.support.boxModel || (verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("Opera"))!=-1);
        // var hCheck = !($.browser.msie || $.browser.opera);
      // resize a textarea
```

On the (original library)

```
(function($) {
// jQuery plugin definition
$.fn.TextAreaExpander = function(minHeight=21, maxHeight) {
var hCheck = !($.browser.msie || $.browser.opera);
```

This is a solution.

Comment: Hi and sorry for the delay, when you have this case and with which browser? (Opera I think that you  use?)

Comment: It was Chrome not working. I resolved copying $.browser from a version of jQuery that hasn't removed it. Then incorporated it into version 1.9

Comment: Thx you have this error because nAgt is not declared!!! Look on the update's my answer. Scusa...

Answer (score 1):

Which version of jQuery are you using? [`jQuery.browser`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/) has been deprecated in jQuery 1.3 and removed in jQuery 1.9

Comment: <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
How to coorect for working this sentence?

Comment: The jQuery version your are using is still supporting `jQuery.browser`, see http://jsbin.com/azebuf/1 for a demo. Please try and reproduce your issue on http://jsbin.com or http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: ie: undefined

opera: undefined

mozilla: true

Comment: Help me for created theproject on js.bin and jsdiffle.net because I don't call the plugin on the site.
Information:
<textarea id=help" class="expand"></textarea> for calling the plugin for expander

Comment: The solution is for me var hCheck = !(jQuery.support.boxModel || (verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("Opera"))!=-1);

Answer (score 1):

$.browser has been removed from jQuery 1.9

use jQuery migrate to fix your code for the moment:

http://blog.jquery.com/2013/02/16/jquery-migrate-1-1-1-released/

then refactor using feature detection

Comment: I have new error and replace the old my library 's query with this twolibrary
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.js">

error:
JQMIGRATE: Logging is active

jquery....1.1.js (línea 21)

JQMIGRATE: jQuery is not compatible with Quirks Mode

Comment: specify a doctype as first line in your documents https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/blob/master/warnings.md#jqmigrate-jquery-is-not-compatible-with-quirks-mode , same page also talks about $.browser https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/blob/master/warnings.md#jqmigrate-jquerybrowser-is-deprecated

Comment: Devo cambiare tutto sto pasticcio!!! Non posso cambiar solamente sta frase.
Tu che librerie usi per jquery e jquery-ui?

Comment: Trovato
var hCheck = !(jQuery.support.boxModel || (verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("Opera"))!=-1);