# jQuery UI Datepicker - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui

I've developed a website in WordPress and installed the Gravity Forms plugin (http://www.gravityforms.com/). I have added a book online form to a page, but the datepicker is returning the following error in the console when clicked:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined

http://ultimatepaintball.com.au/packages/book-online/

Has anyone experienced this issue before? I read somewhere that it may be an issue with jQuery 1.9 and $.browser, but the issue persists even when I fall back to 1.8.3.

Thanks.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9638247/is-jquery-browser-deprecated

Comment: Thanks, mate. I have tried enqueuing jQuery migrate already, as well as falling back to jQuery 1.8.3, neither of which resolved the issue unfortunately.

Comment: Step 1 is to reduce the error to the minimum code that displays the error. Pointing to a page with a 10 or 12 external scripts (mostly minified) plus umpteen internal script elements is not helpful. The problem is that `$.browser` is not defined, you need to work out what is stomping on it (or get a better date picker, is isn't hard to write one).

Comment: Is it only MSIE that's throwing this error? Sounds like a jQuery check for msie, but it seems that jQuery as an object doesn't exist. So could be a lib conflict.

Comment: Just FYI, I experienced this problem when attempting to use mismatched versions of jQuery and jQuery-UI. (Older jQuery-UI was apparently calling deprecated jQuery functions).

Answer (score 1):

not sure , but I think you will need to use the no conflict method http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

OR

change all your `$` signs to `jQUery` on the scripts

OR

```
(function( $ ) {
  $.fn.myPlugin = function() {
    // Do your awesome plugin stuff here
  };
})( jQuery );
```

or some method combining all of the above .

you can also search this site for similar questions :

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jquery+conflict