# senamion does not work properly , with error in browser version

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using senamion plug in from [this](http://www.senamion.com/blog/jmultiselect2side.html) link to create multiside select box , it shows the multiside layout , but on clicking doent works , and doesnt sends the selected items in to next box

in my browser console i get ,

```
TypeError: $.browser is undefined
http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.multiselect2side.js?body=1
Line 278
```

Comment: Tadaa! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9638247/is-jquery-browser-deprecated

Comment: @elclanrs : thanc man , this is it , got it resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Documentation [Link](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/) The $.browser property is deprecated..You may add the following code as a script file after adding ur jquery.js file to know ur browser information.

```
(function() {

    var matched, browser;

    jQuery.uaMatch = function( ua ) {
        ua = ua.toLowerCase();

        var match = /(chrome)[ \/]([\w.]+)/.exec( ua ) ||
            /(webkit)[ \/]([\w.]+)/.exec( ua ) ||
            /(opera)(?:.*version|)[ \/]([\w.]+)/.exec( ua ) ||
            /(msie) ([\w.]+)/.exec( ua ) ||
            ua.indexOf("compatible") < 0 && /(mozilla)(?:.*? rv:([\w.]+)|)/.exec( ua ) ||
            [];

        return {
            browser: match[ 1 ] || "",
            version: match[ 2 ] || "0"
        };
    };

    matched = jQuery.uaMatch( navigator.userAgent );
    browser = {};

    if ( matched.browser ) {
        browser[ matched.browser ] = true;
        browser.version = matched.version;
    }

// Chrome is Webkit, but Webkit is also Safari.
    if ( browser.chrome ) {
        browser.webkit = true;
    } else if ( browser.webkit ) {
        browser.safari = true;
    }

    jQuery.browser = browser;

    jQuery.sub = function() {
        function jQuerySub( selector, context ) {
            return new jQuerySub.fn.init( selector, context );
        }
        jQuery.extend( true, jQuerySub, this );
        jQuerySub.superclass = this;
        jQuerySub.fn = jQuerySub.prototype = this();
        jQuerySub.fn.constructor = jQuerySub;
        jQuerySub.sub = this.sub;
        jQuerySub.fn.init = function init( selector, context ) {
            if ( context && context instanceof jQuery && !(context instanceof jQuerySub) ) {
                context = jQuerySub( context );
            }

            return jQuery.fn.init.call( this, selector, context, rootjQuerySub );
        };
        jQuerySub.fn.init.prototype = jQuerySub.fn;
        var rootjQuerySub = jQuerySub(document);
        return jQuerySub;
    };

})();
```