# CSS3 Padding top and bottom for Chrome only

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit

I have been searching the web for a chrome only solution. I need to modify something in a stylesheet in Chrome only, but I cannot seem to find what I'm looking for online nor on stackoverflow. Chrome has the following for padding left and right

> -webkit-padding-start
>
> -webkit-padding-end

But, is there anything for top AND bottom? OR, am I out of luck?

Comment: What's the reasoning for Chrome only? Usually it's IE..

Comment: As stupid as it sounds, I cannot modify the padding in Chrome more than what I am "allowed" by Chrome. Strange. It looks bigger in Chrome than IE or FF.

Comment: browser sniffing in CSS is a challenge http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/browser-specific-hacks/ jquery has $.browser

Comment: @Wayne I took a look at the website, and is it me or is it confusing? I am still unsure how you could use those. I am referring to comments vs actual coding interpreted as coding by the browsers. Will look at jquery for fun.

Comment: @Wayne uhm, read this. It might interest you [jquery stuff](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9638247/is-jquery-browser-deprecated/#answer-9638284)

Comment: @KungFuFrontEnder browser sniffing is depreciated with html5; although it still exists. It makes for pages that break on future releases as browsers become more standardized. None the less there are still times we need to address one browsers non-standards issue. Feature support is the best way to go forward, IF it works.

Comment: @Wayne fair enough, although I try to use HTML5 standards at all times lol.

Comment: @KungFuFrontEnder me too. But I keep bookmarking all the hacks just in case the browsers let me down.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use `-webkit-padding-before` for `top` padding, `-webkit-padding-after` for bottom padding.

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/CTqb5/1/)

(Top) - `-webkit-padding-before`

(Right - `-webkit-padding-end`

(Bottom) - `-webkit-padding-after`

(Left) - `-webkit-padding-start`

[image]

Comment: That's exactly it. Kudos Josh for the concise and precise explanation! I would upvote you, but I don't have enough rep to do that yet.

Comment: @KungFuFrontEnder You're welcome, that just bumped me to 10k, so it's all good :)

Comment: LOL, well, that IS awesome!

Comment: This is for Safari too, though

Answer (score 1):

This hack looks like it may do the trick.

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
/* rules only apply in saf3+, chrome1+ */
}
```

Comment: This is for android phones, unless I'm mistaking.