# Datepicker not working when using google api

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

```
 <!doctype html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.css">

    <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!--<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>-->

  <script>
  $(function() {
      $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
  </script>

</head>
<body>
    <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

My date picker works if I comment out the ajax.google line. I thought the date picker is part of the jquery UI.  what am I doing wrong or missing?

Comment: I don't understand... You seem to be saying its working with the ajax line commented out... So what's the problem?

Comment: I need the ajax.google for my file upload plugin. if I uncomment that line the file upload works but the datepicker would break.

Answer (score 0):

I obviously can't tell what's in your local jQuery files, but Google's copy of 1.8.18 works just fine:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="demo">
    <input type="text" id="datepicker">
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eqd4x1rq/2/

Comment: I am using jquery 1.10.2  and it is not working with that. but for the file upload it requires 1.8.18 so I am mixing and matching.

Comment: You can't load two different versions of jquery-ui's (if I'm understanding you correctly).
And it shouldn't matter if you're using 1.10.2 or 1.8.18 with regards to the datepicker. It's supported in both versions.

Comment: no I am not using two UIs.  I am using jquery 1.10.2 as in line two of your sample.

Comment: if you go to jfiddle and change 1.4.2 to 1.10.2 it will not work.

Comment: Which file upload plugin are you using? That seems to be the constraint here, as datepicker works fine if you use newer versions of jquery-ui (like 1.10.2 for instance).

Comment: Anyway, the cause of it not working for you, is most definitely the jquery/jquery-ui mismatch. You can read more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9638247/is-jquery-browser-deprecated

Comment: i don't see that using newer versions of jquery-ui causes issues with that file upload plugin. Isn't the answer to your problems to just use latest versions of jquery and jquery-ui?