# How to increase margin-right value only for Chrome in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I need some help to achieve my website. I have a div animated in JS that slides into the screen from right to left (with a button and by a margin-right action). It works fine in Firefox but not in Chrome : with the same value on margin-right, I see the div entirely in FF when showed, but not in GG, I only see a part of it.

The same problem appears for hiding the div; the value isn't high enough so there's still a visible part. I set a higher value for Chrome with "`-webkit-margin-end`" in my CSS, that helped for hidding, but when showed the problem remains. I guess I have to add a Chrome option in my script, so the "margin-right" value (or the "`-webkit-margin-end`" value ?) could be increased too when animated, but I actually can't find any answer to my request.

That's probably because I'm not good enough to apply it to my code, and that's why a bit help would really be appreciated.
Furthermore, is there a way to slide on page load ? I'd like the div 'open' when the user enters the website.

Here's a piece of my code :

```
/* CSS */


/* div */
#texte {
background-color:#FFFFFF;
border-left:0.5px solid #000000;
color:#000000;
font-size:0.9vw;
font-weight:normal;
font-family:"Proza Libre", sans-serif;
top:0;
bottom:0;
right:0;
margin-right:-125px;
-webkit-margin-end:-350px;
width:19.4%;
padding:1vw 0.6vw 1vw 1vw;
float:right;
position:fixed;
display:block;
z-index:1000;
overflow-x:hidden;
overflow-y:auto;
}


/* button */
#plus {
bottom:2.5vw;
right:2.5vw;
position:fixed;
color:#000000;
text-align:center;
font-family:serif;
font-size: 2.5vw;
font-weight:normal;
line-height:2.5vw;
text-decoration:none;
cursor:pointer;
z-index:1000;
border: 0.8px solid #000;
-webkit-border-radius: 50%;
-moz-border-radius: 50%;
border-radius: 50%;
width:2.5vw;
height:2.5vw;
}


/* SCRIPT */


jQuery.easing.def = 'easeOutBounce';

$('#plus').click(function() {
if($(this).css("margin-right") == "125px")  {
$('#texte').animate({"margin-right": '-=125'}, 'slow');
$('#plus').animate({"margin-right": '-=125'}, 'slow');
}
else {
$('#texte').animate({"margin-right": '+=125'}, 'slow');
$('#plus').animate({"margin-right": '+=125'}, 'slow');
}

});
```

**Firefox :**

[image]

**Chrome :**

[image]

Comment: Furthermore, is there a way to slide on page load ? I'd like the div 'open' when the user enters the website. Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than finding an ad-hoc solution for each browser-specific bug maybe you can try finding a way to make your code work the same way for every browser.

I would avoid manipulating the margins. Instead I suggest having one main `DIV` with a fixed width and then have another `DIV` inside with the paddings you need. Then do the animation with the `right` attribute.

Check this snippet and see if this demo works for you.

```js
function togglePanel() {
  if (parseInt($('#main').css('right')) == 0) {
    // get the current width (+ horizontal padding) (+ the border size * 2)
    width = $('#main').width() + parseInt($('#main').css('padding-left')) + parseInt($('#main').css('padding-right')) + 2;
    $('#main').animate({"right": -width}, 'slow');
  } else {
    $('#main').animate({"right": 0}, 'slow');
  }
}

$('#toggleMain').on('click', function() {
  togglePanel();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  togglePanel();
});
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

#main {
  background:blue;
  position:absolute;
  padding:10px;
  right:-222px;
  top:0px;
  bottom:0px;
  width:200px;
  border:1px solid red;
  }

#inner {
  width:100%;
  padding:10px;
  border:1px solid green;
  background:orange;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main"><div id="inner">Here goes the text<br/>and more text</div></div>
<button id="toggleMain">Toggle</button>
```

Comment: Just a hint: when possible, use the latest jquery version which is 3.x. The 2.x versions are just for "still supporting IE8" if I remember correctly.

Comment: @Gunnar Thank you, I just picked it from the snippet interface dropdown menu. There is nothing beyond 2.2.1 there and it seems to work fine. I could add it myself but since there was no talk about version in OPs question I didn't pay much attention to it, but thanks for the hint.

Comment: i see, thank you, i didn't work with stackoverflow code snippets so far.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, for detecting if chrome and adding margin.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var isChrome = !!window.chrome;

  if(isChrome) {
    $(".element").css("margin-right", "30px");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Browser detection is no good practice, see for example [Is jQuery $.browser Deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9638247/is-jquery-browser-deprecated)

A better way is to provide general cross browser solutions.

You could for example use [normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) and then apply your own css. This maybe makes the css "resets" you need, so your own css looks good/equal in all browsers.

Comment: No good and boring ! Thank you for your option, but I tried Eric Meyer's css reset, and doesn't change anything.