# Change cursor while painted on canvas using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

I have fixed myself a `canvas` which can be painted on  + [disable selection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4358620/859154) + [detecting cross browser when the mouse is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6180819/859154).

Here it is : http://jsfiddle.net/EsYqm/52/

But how can I change the cursor (nevermind to which ) while i'm pressing the left mouse click ( which means - **while** painting )

(im using chrome 27)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your CSS...

```
body {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
canvas:active, canvas:focus { 
    cursor: crosshair; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
   $('canvas').css( 'cursor', 'text' );
```

after `if (letsdraw === true)`

so your condition would be

```
   if (letsdraw === true)
    {
        $('canvas').css( 'cursor', 'text' );
        ctx.lineTo(e.pageX - canvasOffset.left, e.pageY - canvasOffset.top);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
```