# Cell selection stops when mouse move fast on table

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-7

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LtRN8/4/)

```
var flag=false;

$(document).live('mouseup', function () { flag = false; });
var colIndex; var lastRow;
$(document).on('mousedown', '.csstablelisttd', function (e) {
    //This line gets the index of the first clicked row.
    lastRow = $(this).closest("tr")[0].rowIndex;    

    var rowIndex = $(this).closest("tr").index();
    colIndex = $(e.target).closest('td').index();
    $(".csstdhighlight").removeClass("csstdhighlight");
    if (colIndex == 0 || colIndex == 1) //)0 FOR FULL TIME CELL AND 1 FOR TIME SLOT CELL. 
        return;
    if ($('#contentPlaceHolderMain_tableAppointment tr').eq(rowIndex).find('td').eq(colIndex).hasClass('csstdred') == false)
    {
        $('#contentPlaceHolderMain_tableAppointment tr').eq(rowIndex).find('td').eq(colIndex).addClass('csstdhighlight');

        flag = true;
        return false;
    }     
});


document.onmousemove = function () { return false; };

$(".csstablelisttd").live('mouseenter', function (e) {
    // Compares with the last and next row index.
    var currentRow = $(this).closest("tr")[0].rowIndex;
    var currentColoumn = $(e.target).closest('td').index();

    // cross row selection
    if (lastRow == currentRow || lastRow == currentRow - 1 || lastRow == currentRow + 1)
    {
        lastRow = $(this).closest("tr")[0].rowIndex;
    }
    else
    {
        flag = false;
        return;
    }
    // cross cell selection.
    if (colIndex != currentColoumn)
    {
        flag = false;
        return;
    }

    if (flag)
    {
        $('#contentPlaceHolderMain_tableAppointment tr').eq(currentRow).find('td').eq(currentColoumn).addClass('csstdhighlight');
        e.preventDefault();                     
        return false;
    }                          
});
```

Cell selection stops when I move the cursor fast over the table.
What should I do to prevent the selection from stopping while moving the cursor fast on table cells.
I dont want to change the html of the page.
The problem mostly occurs in IE 7.
I have handled the event mousedown, mouseenter on tr class.

Comment: Took a really quick look. My first guess is that is has to do with the check of being "plus or minus" one row away. Hopefully that can send you on a path to fixing the issue. I'll look back at this later when I have a bit more time.

Comment: travJenkins checked andyb answers fiddle but i have notice some faults when i click on only cell then highlight cell selection.other one point i have notice there is cross selection happens.when move mouse around table.

Answer (score 0):

I think the *selection logic* is incorrectly getting stuck in a `flag = false` state.

When the mouse moves quickly the `lastRow == currentRow || lastRow == currentRow - 1 || lastRow == currentRow + 1` will evaluate to `false` since the currentRow is not next to the lastRow, therefore `flag` is set to `false` (in the *else*). Then for all subsequent `mouseenter` events flag will always be false and the highlight class will never get added.

The problem occurs on Chrome also and I assume is far more pronounced on IE7 because the JavaScript engine is so much slower in IE7. I think that the JavaScript is quite complex and also the [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) jQuery function should be avoided since it was removed in jQuery 1.9. [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) (as you already use in another event binding) is the preferred method now.

I have included an alternate approach to highlighting the last table cell of each row if the left mouse button is held down, which is a lot simpler. If I have understood the code correctly, the only functionality missing is checking if a current row is either side of a previous row, as I couldn't see a good reason for this extra checking.

There is still the possibility that if a user is moving the mouse quickly over the rows, I would expect the that some rows **miss** the `mouseenter` event as the mouse is too quick. You may be able to use a `mousemove` event handler on the `<table>` itself to help address this.

The [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2SQ4q/) uses jQuery 1.9.1, and I also removed the table height to better demonstrate the code.

**JavaScript**

```
// disable text selection
document.onselectstart = function() {
    return false;
}

var $table = $('#contentPlaceHolderMain_tableAppointment');

$table.on('mouseenter', 'td:last-child', function(e) {
    if (e.which === 1) {
        $(this).addClass('csstdhighlight');
    }
}).on('click', function() {
    $table.find('.csstdhighlight').removeClass('csstdhighlight');
});
```

I'd be happy to explain my example code in more detail if necessary :-)

Note: An answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/6195715/637889) on [jQuery: Detecting pressed mouse button during mousemove event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065992/jquery-detecting-pressed-mouse-button-during-mousemove-event) was very helpful when I was looking at this.

**Edit:** [**Updated demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2SQ4q/1/) based on revised requirements:

**JavaScript**

```
// disable text selection
document.onselectstart = function() {
    return false;
}

var $table = $('#contentPlaceHolderMain_tableAppointment');
var startIndex = -1;
var direction = 0;

$table.on('mouseenter', 'td:last-child', function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var rowIndex = $this.parent().index();
    if (direction === 0 && startIndex != -1) {
        direction = rowIndex > startIndex ? 1 : -1;
    }

    if (e.which === 1 && (
        (direction === -1 && rowIndex < startIndex) ||
        (direction === 1 && rowIndex > startIndex))
       ) {
        $(this).addClass('csstdhighlight');
    }
}).on('mousedown', 'td:last-child', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    startIndex = $this.parent().index();

    $this.addClass('csstdhighlight');
}).on('mouseup', 'td:last-child', function() {
    direction = 0;
    startIndex = -1;
}).on('click', 'td:last-child', function() {
    $table.find('.csstdhighlight').removeClass('csstdhighlight');
});
```

Comment: thanks for ur reply when i click on cell i have to highlight cell selection.one point i have notice there is cross selection happens..

Comment: Andy row selection mismatch

Comment: Yes, I do not completely understand your requirements. Can you explain the "cross selection" part please?

Comment: Row selection must be in sequence..(Means if i select 1st row when drag then row must select its above or its down not any else row)

Comment: Andy i am getting lastRow  and currentRow shall i add class directly to there respective td  So there is no chek of lastrow -1 or +1

Comment: So should it be only 1 row either above or below the selected one?

Comment: I m getting lastrow index and currentrowIndex then we will add cssclass in between and including those index those index

Comment: I have updated the demo and answer with some code that better fits your requirements as I understand them. Hope this helps!

Comment: andyb when i move mouse fast it doesnt select all rows skips smoe row selection

Comment: Yes, as I have explained this is *always* going to happen when using `mouseenter`. With my solution at least a user can still go back to the _missing_ rows and the highlight will work. The only way that this might ever work with very fast moving mouse is to use `mousemove` on the table (as I already explained). Do you _honestly_, really have a requirement for selecting rows with a fast moving mouse? I (and you) have spent far too long developing a solution on the chance a user might be "too fast"! I'm happy to delete this answer if it doesn't work.