# jquery - Event while the mouse is held down

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an image that I have given the id #scroller to. What I would like to do is move the scroller horizontally according to the x-coordinate of the mouse but only when it's held down. I'm trying to move scroller against a hroizontal line called #bar. The amount the scroller can move depends on the width of the bar. Here is my code so far.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var barWidth = $("#bar").width();
    var mouseDown = false;

    $(document).mousedown(function() {
        mouseDown = true;
    });
    $(document).mouseup(function() {
        mouseDown = false;
    });

    $(document).on("mousemove", function(e) {
        if (mouseDown) {
            if (e.pageX >= barWidth) {
                $("#debug").html(JSON.stringify(e.pageX, undefined, 4));
                $("#scroller").css("left", barWidth);
            } else {
                $("#debug").html(JSON.stringify(e.pageX, undefined, 4));
                $("#scroller").css("left", e.pageX);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

The #debug just prints something out on to the screen. It helps in debugging. It's not working as expected. I want the scroller to move when the mouse is held down and moving.

Comment: 1.  I'd kill the #debug and just use the console for debug messages.      2.  How exactly is it "not working as exptected"?  Can you give an example?

Comment: can you post it in codepen ? to watch how it is working now.

Comment: 1) See this to locate buttons pressed when event triggered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065992/jquery-detecting-pressed-mouse-button-during-mousemove-event
2) Please create jsfiddle/speficy wht is not working as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I'm sorry but I don't know how to use jsfiddle or codepen. Also, I just changed one thing. I deleted the .mousedown, and .mouseup functions. and in the place of if (mouseDown), I wrote $(document).on("mousedown", function(e) {. So now what happens is the scroller moves to a new location when the mouse is clicked. It doesn't move again until I let go of the mouse and click it again at a different location. So it's basically moving discretely not continuously. I hope that helps

Comment: @ManyQuestions mouse click event triggered only once after you pushed mouse down and release it while beeing focus on the same element. It won't be trigger again if mouse moved

Comment: Thank you!  This post helped get mine to work!  :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You problem is likely in the fact that you didn't change position attribute for your scroller. It should be either  `style="position:absolute"` or  `style="position:relative"`
otherwise  `.css("left", barWidth)` won't have effect. See js fiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/0m0j35oc/

More over it is better to track buttons on event itself(see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065992/jquery-detecting-pressed-mouse-button-during-mousemove-event) for more details) as mouseup/mousedown event might be triggered outside of the page effectively getting you cached state out of sync. See example here:

https://jsfiddle.net/g0uqLL9n/

Comment: Thank you for that. I have the position set to absolute. I just realized the problem. Now I feel stupid. So the scroller works fine. It's just that the #bar that I used is a large image. So when I click and hold down the mouse in the area of that picture, it doesn't work properly. It works when I click and hold the mouse outside the area of the bar.